# Postgres: New created user can't work with database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm trying to create a new **postgres** user so I don't have to give my personal credentials to another developer. I want this new user to have access to only one database (there are `db` and `db_dev` databases)

The problem is that `shell_plus` says that he doesn't have permissions for particular relation.

What I have done:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
CREATE USER guest WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_dev TO guest;
```

Then I tried:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO guest;
```

But shell keeps raising this error:

```
>>> User.objects.all()
>>> ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation auth_user
```

The similar error is being raised when trying to run development server.

Do you know what to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you granted connect permission on dev_db database to your guest user and usage privilege on public schema